# Angular $resource GET request, incomplete HEADER data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-resource

I am using ionic 1.3 and angular 1.5.

I am trying to access some header properties for my response. The code I have is something like below:

```
factory('Service', function($resource, API_SETTINGS, JsonData) {
  return $resource('/users/path', {}, {
    'fetch': {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer'
      },
      transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter, status) {
        if (data) {
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          return {
            data: data,
            headers: headersGetter()
          };
        }
      }
    }
  });
})
```

The value for headers is:

```
{
  cache-control: 'max-age=0, private, must-revalidate',
  content-type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
}
```

However, the actual response header contains much more than what angular is showing.

[image: Response Header]

Essentially, I need to view the X-User-Count property, but no matter what I do, I cannot access it.

I have added 
`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-User-Count` to both the server, as well as to with the $resouce headers object, but that did not make a difference.

I also downloaded the Chrome extension to toggle CORS, but none of that has made any difference. I look at loads of SO posts about this, but none of them seemed relevant.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Access-Control-Expose-Headers was not correctly added to my server before (I am using rails), and it needed to be added to the resource method:

`:expose => ['X-User-Count']`

For interest's sake, the header object now returns three properties

```
{
  cache-control: 'max-age=0, private, must-revalidate',
  content-type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  x-user-count: 5
}
```

I am adding this because I was not sure what the default header object would look like, but it seems it is just this basic 2 property object.